# How to list certain amount of items in collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically things go that way

```
collection.each do |variable|
   code
end
```

But what do I do if I want to output, for example, only first five items out of my collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    collection.first(5).each do |variable|
```

In Rails AR collection:

```
    Article.first(5)
```

and then you can just go through whole collection, because it will consist 5 records.

Comment: It is working! Thanks a ton! By the way, maybe you'd probably know where I can read about this?

Comment: you can find a lot of the core methods here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html 
You can find last which is equal to first but takes exactly last number of elements

And take method which is equal to first

Comment: But sad thing is that this refuses to work in Rails view.

Comment: @BillyLogan Are you sure ? Could you provide full code example ?